# Convergence almost everywhere criterion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

I was reading Loeve's Probability Theory and I saw the following criterion for determining convergence almost everywhere:

---

**Convergence a.e. criterion.** Let $X, X_n$ be finite measurable functions.

$ X_n \stackrel{\text { a.e. }}{\longrightarrow} X$  if, and only if, for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\qquad \mu \bigcap_n \bigcup_\nu\left[\left|X_{n+\nu}-X\right| \geqq \epsilon\right]=0
$$

and, if $\mu$ is fnite, this criterion becomes
$$
\mu \bigcup_\nu\left[\left|X_{n+\nu}-X\right| \geqq \epsilon\right] \rightarrow 0
$$

---

Here $\mu$ is a measure. I am just curious about the role of finiteness plays here -- why can we simplify the first criterion to the second one when $\mu$ is finite? If $\mu$ is not finite, what problems will we have if we use the second criterion?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it is simply saying that, when $\mu$ is finite, $$\mu\!\left(\bigcap_n A_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\!\!\!\searrow\mu(A_n)\tag{$\star$}$$ for any sequence of non-increasing measurable sets $(A_n)_{n\ge1}$. There are easy counterexamples to $(\star)$ when $\mu$ is not finite.

Comment: @nejimban Hi! Thank you for helping me connect my question to the property of continuity from above! I will look for the counterexamples of this then.